# What does @ mean in the hostname part of a .rhosts file in Solaris?

Tags: solaris, rsh

What does

```
+@foo_hosts username
```

mean in a user's `.rhosts` file?

I presume it is defining a group of hosts in some way, but I can't figure out where to look for the definition of `@foo_hosts`. I found the name `foo_hosts` mentioned in the output of `ypcat netgroup.byhost` but not in a way that seems to associate it with any list of hosts.

`uname` reports `SunOS 5.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is NIS.

The netgroup database is kept on the NIS master server in the file /etc/netgroup or /usr/etc/netgroup. This file consists of one or more lines that have the form:

```
groupname member1 member2 ...
```

After this file is updated (or any other NIS database file for that matter) to make the changes live you have to run a second command, *makedbm* which might be  /etc/yp/makedbm or /usr/etc/yp/makedbm

For further information Check [this documentation](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking/puis/ch19_04.htm)